# Angular App Responsive Only When served Through ng serve

Tags: angular, responsive, ngx-admin

I am facing a really weird issue. I searched for it on SO and other websites but could not find any reference to this issue.

Basically, when I am serving the Angular Ngx-admin app using `ng serve` command, it becomes mobile responsive.

But as soon as I try to serve the `ng build` distribution files through a static server, the app loses the responsiveness.

I tried various ways like NodeJS http-server, simple NodeJS Express App, PM2 Serve (`pm2 serve --spa`) but everything is giving the same output.

I am not getting what is going wrong here.

Here's the screenshot of responsive app using `ng serve`

[image: responsive app using ng serve]

---

Here's the non-responsive app using static file serving

[image: non-responsive app using static file server]

Comment: did you check angular.Json file ? is there any differences between build and serve? specialy in "styles" key

Comment: @AliMirzaie I compared the 2 and found no difference. I had modified the ngx-admin code base which had this issue. I created a new angular application from scratch and it seems to be working fine now. So I am not sure what was the exact cause. Thanks for the help!

Comment: any luck on it? I am facing same issue..

Comment: just changed "optimization": true to "optimization": false in angular build and issue has been resolved. now question comes that whats wrong happening while optimizing our build?